# Validation as you type jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, function

I have this jQuery code for validate the email input as the user types:

```
$('#email').keyup(function() {
    if (!isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
        $('#validate').removeClass();
    } else {
        $('#validate').removeClass();
        $('#validate').addClass('validate');
    }
});​
```

But what if the user as it types for example "Da" the browser recognizes the email and shows an option to complete it in the dropdown like "daniel@gmail.com",, so what event can I use in my jQuery Code to even validate it when the user clicks on that dropdown option or clicks enter to select it...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hook into the `change` event?

Comment: What do you mean by validate?  If the drop-down is there, and the user clicks the option or hits enter, then trigger your validation right then and there.

Comment: @TheZ: `change` irritatingly waits until the user defocuses the box before firing. At least, it does for `<textarea>`s.

Comment: Is the dropdown a browser-supplied autocomplete or does your code do that?

Comment: With validate I mean validating a text field so if its correct, in this case email, if is correctly typed example@example.com .. The dropdown is the default that the browser has..

Answer (score 2):

if you are using jquery 1.7+ bind keyup and change event with the same method:

```
$("#email").on("change keyup", function() {
    $('#validate').toggleClass('validate', isValidEmailAddress(this.value));
});
```

you could shorten your code, you only want to add the css class ´validate´ if the email is valid (I take it that the #email is an input form and you want to validate its value).

remember that jQuery objects returns the collection you have looked up to, so save `$('validate')` to a variable and use that variable instead of making jquery find the element over and over again (up to a couple of times in your code).

if you are using an older version of jQuery just change on to [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this plugin can help you for what you need and then integrate it with the code you already have.

**Take a look at this demo:**

http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Keyup and Change:

```
$("#email").change(validate).keyup(validate);;

function validate()
{
if (!isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
        $('#validate').removeClass();
    } else {
        $('#validate').removeClass();
        $('#validate').addClass('validate');
    } 
}
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/Z8Z7b/7/
​